# Change Timezone for Date object Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonanywhere

Hello I am using [Pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) and when I call

```
from datetime import *

print date.today().day
```

It is printing a different day than the day it is where I live (Austin, Texas). I figured it is because there is a timezone difference. How would I tell the date object where I live so it gets the right timezone. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most robust way to do this is to use `pytz`. You can install it simply with `pip install pytz`.

To get the local date with `pytz`, you can simply do this (note that the `date.today` method will not take a timezone):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> local_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))  # use datetime here
>>> local_date.date()                                       # now call date method
datetime.date(2014, 11, 30)
```

Compare that to the present Greenwich date:

```
>>> greenwich_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Etc/Greenwich'))
>>> greenwich_date.date()
datetime.date(2014, 12, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standard library, there is no cross-platform way to create aware timezones without creating your own timezone class. The pytz library has an up-to-date database of most timezones. You can therefore do:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

The `.utc` gives you a localized timezone by default, but you may wish to explicitly provide another timezone using `.timezone()` method.